# Black screenshot randomly taken with Selenium PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium with PhantomJS via Python.

The problem I'm encountering is that I am getting black screenshots seemingly at random. For instance, this page renders a black 400x300 png file:

http://ib.adnxs.com/cr?id=17708944

Using the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) " +
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C:\Python27\Lib\phantomjs.exe", 
                             desired_capabilities=dcap)

driver.get('http://ib.adnxs.com/cr?id=17708944')
driver.save_screenshot('foo.png')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I followed the link and see a big white square (nothing) :)

Comment: Hi @alecxe, what's supposed to load is an ad. Do you have something like AdBlocker enabled? Disabling it should allow it to load properly.

Comment: Ah, sure, correct - it was an adblocker. Thank you.